# How to get Notepad to enter fullscreen?

Tags: windows, windows-10, notepad

Windows Notepad is my favorite text reader on Windows 10. It takes very little ram, allows me to customize font, and has clean interface. How can I make it go full screen like TextEdit on MacOS?

Answer (score 0):

Notepad does not offer a true full-screen feature.

The only alternative I can think of is this one:

If you want notepad to remember this position for every time you open it (either when starting notepad or when opening a file through explorer) make sure you drag the edges of the window, and not use the maximize button. Also, when you drag the edges and windows snaps the window (it suddenly is perfectly in height or width or both) windows will not remember it either.

You can see this is happening if a circle is showing around the mouse cursor. The only way to not get it to snap is either to turn off the feature or alter the size of the window pixel by pixel. So you resize it to about 20 pixels away from the border then release the mouse button. Then you click and drag a few pixels at the time and release again. This way, windows will not start the snap feature and you can resize it to fully fit the screen.

Once done, close notepad and the setting is remembered.

Comment: interesting what you say we windows remembering/not and resizing. Is this in XP too?  (not the snapping), but the rest re when it remembers and when it doesn't? i.e. that xp too, won't remember when you maximized it but will remember when you resized it?

Comment: @barlop yes, this is also true for windows XP. I just tested it and it behaves exactly like this in windows 2000 too. I think notepad always behaved like this, since windows 95. I do think this is specifically true for notepad though, not every program does this. And some programs can be made to remember using ctrl+close program.

Comment: Can anyone please explain me the downvotes? Notepad does not offer fullscreen, so I provide a good alternative. This really is not worth downvoting.

Comment: I can take a guess, because I almost downvoted you because at first glance your post read like a bad answer, but then I saw it was not a bad answer so I didn't downvote you. Your first sentence isn't well put. You start by saying you're not sure, well, if you're not sure and that not sureness is relevant, relevant enough for you to state it, then you should comment.  And if he means one of two possibilities and it doesn't matter  he means because you can answer either way, then just state both meanings and (cnt)

Comment: no need to say say you're not sure.   You can say it depends what you mean by... if you mean.. W then X, if you mean Y then Z. That way you're covering not just for the OP's particular unspecified situation but for the question that has been asked.  The first interpretation that you put on what he meant, was the lame one. So your first sentence sounds like a double whammy of lameness.  And his question was quite short, You could've said,   "Of course i'm sure you don't mean the maximise option, (which can be done with this button... ) but you most probably mean stretching it so(cnt)

Comment: The title bar isn't visible, so even bigger than maximized. This is not possible in notepad.   You're not really concisely saying that and your first sentence says you're not sure AND interprets his question in a poor way.

Comment: (cont)And the last 3 paragraphs  ["If you",  "You can",  "Once done"] are interesting but should be prefaced with "As a side point" because while it's very interesting, it doesn't address the question.  And a minor point,  your final sentence, in its separate paragraph, that last line on its own, could be worded better, it sounds like bam you've answered it "once done", you say. It should be more self-contained. like "Once you have set its position and size, then it's remembered". So nobody at first glance would think Oh that must be talking about solving it.

Comment: (cont) and you could make it more clear that aside from the clear answer of it's not possible..(which you could add to by saying BECAUSE...), but aside from that clear answer you give of no, not possible,   the rest of your answer isn't really answering the question. It may be really useful and interesting and of value, but worth acknowledging that the answer is no (pref if u can say because XYZ), and as a side point, blah. And don't make your last line or any line make it look like you solved it/answer yes, when you didn't. That'd be a nicely structured answer that makes sense at first glance

Comment: @barlop thanks for the insight. I've edited my answer. Is it better now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44205/discussion-between-barlop-and-lpchip).

Answer (score 0):

I've worked out a script in AutoHotkey for this just now, thanks for the interesting idea. I've only tested it on Windows 7, so I hope it works on Windows 10 too. It uses two key combinations to turn fullscreen on/off. It resizes the windows, expands it a bit beyond the screen to hide the scrollbars, and removes the menu bar and title bar.

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class Notepad
^q:: ;notepad fullscreen on
WinGet, hWnd, ID, A
WinGetClass, vWinClass, ahk_id %hWnd%
if vWinClass not in Notepad
Return

WinGet, vWinMinMax, MinMax, ahk_id %hWnd%
if (vWinMinMax = 1) ;1=max/0=res/1=min
WinRestore, ahk_id %hWnd%

if (hMenu%hWnd% = "")
hMenu%hWnd% := DllCall("GetMenu", "uint", hWnd)

if (vPos%hWnd% = "") OR (vWinMinMax = 0)
{
WinGetPos, vPosX, vPosY, vPosW, vPosH, ahk_id %hWnd%
vPos%hWnd% := vPosX "," vPosY "," vPosW "," vPosH
}

WinSet, Style, -0xC00000, ahk_id %hWnd% ;hide title bar
DllCall("SetMenu", "uint", hWnd, "uint", 0) ;hide menu bar
WinMove, ahk_id %hWnd%, , 0, 0, % A_ScreenWidth + 20, % A_ScreenHeight + 20
Return

;==================================================

^w:: ;notepad fullscreen off
WinGet, hWndZ, ID, A
WinGetClass, vWinClassZ, ahk_id %hWndZ%
if vWinClassZ not in Notepad
Return

hMenuZ := hMenu%hWndZ%
if (hMenuZ = "")
Return
vPosZ := vPos%hWndZ%

WinSet, Style, +0xC00000, ahk_id %hWndZ% ;show title bar
DllCall("SetMenu", "uint", hWndZ, "uint", hMenuZ) ;show menu bar
StringSplit, vPosZ, vPosZ, `,
WinMove, ahk_id %hWnd%, , %vPosZ1%, %vPosZ2%, %vPosZ3%, %vPosZ4%
Return
#IfWinActive
```

Answer (score -1):

Notepad can now become fullscreen by key F11.

Comment: F11 does nothing in the Notepad in my Windows 10.